# Groovy/Grails - get HttpResponseException by using HTTPBuilder

Tags: rest, grails, groovy, uri, httpbuilder

I try to get a data of Grails application (MyApplication2) from another Grails application (MyApplication2). Boths application run locally.
I get an exception thrown using the following code.

**Groovy**

```
try {
    def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://localhost:8080/MyApplication2')

    http.get( path : '/ControllerName/Action', contentType : ContentType.TEXT) { resp, reader ->

            println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
            resp.headers.each { h ->
                println " ${h.name} : ${h.value}"
            }

        }
} catch (groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
    println ex.toString()

} catch (java.net.ConnectException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
    println ex.toString()       
}
```

**Exception thrown**

```
 Error 2015-10-28 10:13:43,448 [http-bio-8090-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - HttpResponseException occurred when processing request: [GET] /MyApplication1/ControllerName/Action Not Found.
```

Comment: try catch ? https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/jenkins/HBuilder.groovy#L25-L30

Comment: I added try catch, "groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found" is catched

Comment: Hmm, maybe get rid of the extra / at the end of the controller/action block?

Comment: I get the same result

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem: I changed The `URI` format.
I added at the end of the `URI` a `/`, and I removed the `/` at the beginning of the `path`.

```
try {

        def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://localhost:8080/MyApplication2/')

        http.get( path : 'ControllerName/Action', contentType : ContentType.TEXT) { resp, reader ->

        println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
        resp.headers.each { h ->
            println " ${h.name} : ${h.value}"
        }

    }
} catch (groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
    println ex.toString()

} catch (java.net.ConnectException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace()
    println ex.toString()       
}
```